# Tensorboard: Show all summaries of single run

Tags: python, tensorflow, linegraph, tensorboard

I need to run my machine learning program in tensorflow and write the summary in a file (to display for tensorboard). Assume that the program can stop freely at any time.

However, the problem is Tensorflow will write a new summary in a as a new file. Tensorboard will show only linegraph the latest summary (overwriting the previous ones). I want to show both the latest summary and the previous one.

I would be grateful if anyone can provide some guidance on this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the summaries to the different subdirectories, e.g. for the first run, save to `logs/run1`, and for the second to `logs/run2`. When you start tensorboard as:

```
tensorboard --logdir logs
```

Then both of your runs will be depicted on common plots (where applicable).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand your solutions about runs. Howerver is there anyway to continue my run on the same graph (with the same line color, line graph, etc...) on my first, second and third run? Because I have multiple other runs as well (test, train...)